# jQuery remove selected classes content from html

Tags: jquery

I need to grab the content of a #container, except the class .removethis

```
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
   <div class="removethis">sed</div> do 
   <div class="removethis">eiusmod</div> tempor incididunt ut labore et <b>dolore</b> magna aliqua. 
</div>
```

My attempt `$('#container').remove('.removethis'); alert($('#container').html());`

Comment: have you tried `$('#container').remove('.removethis').html()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. If you want to remove `.removethis` from the html

Do `$('.removethis').remove();`  to remove `.removethis` elements.

```js
$('.removethis').remove();
console.log($('#container').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  <div class="removethis">sed</div> do
  <div class="removethis">eiusmod</div> tempor incididunt ut labore et <b>dolore</b> magna aliqua. </div>
```

#### 2. If you do not want to remove `.removethis` from the html but just while fetching the content

Or incase you do not actually want to remove the `.removethis` but just dont want it when fetching the HTML then take a clone of `#container` and remove `.removethis` from that.

```js
var e = $('#container').clone();
$('.removethis', e).remove();
console.log(e.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  <div class="removethis">sed</div> do
  <div class="removethis">eiusmod</div> tempor incididunt ut labore et <b>dolore</b> magna aliqua. </div>
```